# How to update the data constantly after using API in Getx Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a getx controller and a method to update data in the database, I just wonder that how can I refresh of update the UI constantly after fetching the API? Here is my controller

```
class AdditionalContactController extends GetxController {
  var additionalContactList = <AdditionalContact>[].obs;
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  UserController _userController = Get.find();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    _userController.getMail().then((value) async {
      await _userController.getUser(value);
      getAdditionalContacts(_userController.user.value.id);
    });
  }

  //Update contact
  Future<bool> updateContact({...}) async {
    var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(
            "https://..."),
        body: {
          ...
        });
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (jsonData == "failed") {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use `Obx`.

Comment: @JohnJoe, I also have a method to get the data, and my purpose is fetching that data and show on the observable  list, and then update if needed, but when i update the data, how can i also update the data in the observable list? can you explain that? thank you

Comment: maybe show us the observable list ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `ever` worker to call a method that executes every time an `Rx` have assigned with a new value:

```
    class AdditionalContactController extends GetxController {
  var additionalContactList = <AdditionalContact>[].obs;

     @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
   ever(additionalContactList, methodToExecute)
 });
  }



  methodToExecute(list) {
   /* Code that will execute every time the additionalContactList changes */
    }
```

now everytime `additionalContactList` is changed like as example if we assign a new `List` to it:

```
additionalContactList.value = [];
```

Then the `methodToExecute()` will be executed automatically, and will do every single time.